# Proxy changes IP?

Tags: ip

I want to hide my IP.

I want to log-in into a JAVA game with the hidden IP, does a Proxy does so?
If I get a proxy like hotspotshield, will it show the hotspot IP in the java game connection logs?

Answer (score 2):

Proxy hides your IP, which means that on server will show IP of proxy server.